# Confused about logical statement simplification

Tags: logic

We are trying to solve an assignment where we have to simplify a logical statement. Can anyone explain what is going on this step?
$$(\neg P\lor \neg Q)\land (\neg P\lor Q) \equiv \neg P\lor(\neg Q\land Q)$$

How do we get from $(\neg P\lor \neg Q)\land(\neg P \lor Q)$ to $\neg P\lor(\neg Q\land Q)$? What simplification rule is being used here?

Comment: Use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the [Distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

We have
$$(P\land (Q\lor R)) \equiv (P\land Q)\lor (P\land R)$$
$$(P\lor (Q\land R)) \equiv (P\lor Q)\land (P\lor R)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is distributivity of disjunction over conjunction: $A \vee (B \wedge C)$ is equivalent to $(A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$.